# SublimeText won't let me compile C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, sublimetext

I keep getting the same error on a simple piece of code after I downloaded multiple compilers and added them to 'PATH' in windows settings

Error :

```
E:\Programs\sublimeProjects\helloWorld: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 985ms]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the entire compilation output.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded multiple compilers and added them to 'PATH' in windows settings

This is a very bad idea. You will run into a complete mess where parts of one compiler interfere with parts of the other compiler due to them all being on the PATH.

I would recommend to immediately remove all compilers from the PATH.  Instead, what you should do is have a batch file or shell script that you run to set up the environment for just that window.

Some compiler installations come already set up this way (e.g. mingw-w64/MSYS2).

In SublimeText you can set it to use that batch file or script to set up the build environment, e.g. see https://gist.github.com/sagebind/9039773048a3900fa49a .